# How can this circuit read a value for amps at 0 volts

Tags: voltage, current, ohms-law

I made a simple circuit using [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/):

It can tell you the voltage and current along a wire if you mouse over it. The wire down the bottom reads 4.55mA and 0V (the little yellow dots actually move to show current, and the green colouring is voltage).

I don't get how that can be. If there is no voltage how can anything possibly be moving? And if nothing can move, that implies no current. Where does 4.55mA come from? If I remove the 1k resistor, it goes up to 50mA and still 0V. It doesn't make sense to me.

[image: amps]

Answer (score 3):

Some basic facts of elementary electricity:

- Voltage is measured between two points; when mention is made of voltage at some point, that is relative to an implicit reference, the "ground"; which most often (and here) is the negative side of the power supply.
- As a first order approximation, there is no voltage across a piece of metal wire, even if some current flows inside it.

Considering these two facts, it is normal that the simulator shows no voltage on any wire connected to the negative pole of the power supply, just as observed.

Comment: Related: [Equipotential Surfaces](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys213/lectures/equipot/equipot_long.html). Information at that link explains the 0V potential difference when referring to two points on a single conductor.

Comment: I really need this explained at a more fundamental level. I simply can't work out in my head how a charge can move between the end of the 1k resistor and the negative terminal on the supply when there is no potential between those points to move it.

Comment: @Cameron Ball: First think of that wire as a 1 ohm resistor (corresponding to a very thin and long wire); there is a (small) potential across it, and that's what moves the charges. That potential is U=RI, where I is the current in that wire and other components. R is actually very small (because the wire really is thick), thus U is near zero. Thus charges move along the wire with almost no difference of potential across it (my second bullet).

Answer (score 0):

It reads 0V because the simulator is using the negative terminal of the supply as ground. If you inspect the voltage at other nodes of the circuit you will find non-zero values.

Comment: Yes but between the right hand side of the 1k resistor and the ground terminal there is 0V, so how can current move there?

Comment: Because Kirchoff's current law says that it must.

Comment: @CameronBall, [Kirchoff's Current Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws). In summary, the sum of currents entering a node must equal the sum of currents leaving the same node - in this case the negative terminal of the supply.

Answer (score 0):

Every point in a circuit has a well define voltage and a current (in steady state) that can be found through mesh analysis (KVL/KCL). Since this particular circuit is a single series loop, the current at every point in the circuit will be the same (namely Vcc/1100, from which I can infer that your battery voltage must be 5V ~= 0.00455 * 1100). If that weren't true, you'd build up charge somewhere in the circuit until some cataclysmic event ensued.

The voltage however will drop across each resistor starting from the positive terminal of the battery, by an amount I * R. So the voltage just past the first resistor will be 5V - 0.00455 * 100 = 4.545V. And the voltage just past the second resistor will obviously be zero because it is connected to the negative terminal of the battery.